# Why won't this decrypt?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, aes

I've been trying to get this to work for a while. So, I'm trying to make an API and it uses POST Requests (Obviously). It should decrypt to `{"action":"initialize","application_id":"2ToERP8VaSfkfrpGTn37I75lZ9Q9ZRHIIU56w5GAZ8MWp"}`. But for some reason it doesn't. It decrypts fine here,

```
function DecryptMessage($message, $program)
{
    $enckey = 'XXSAGalY532n3AfVM36ugBczzdtwkxC6Rai1so3ajf90yMZYfOr2'; //This is what the MySQL is for..
    $method = 'aes-256-cbc';
    $password = substr(hash('sha256', $enckey, true), 0, 32);
    $iv = chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0);
    $decrypted = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($message), $method, $password, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    return $decrypted;
}
$result = DecryptMessage('3dT6n4BVehzG1d3hO25aUIekEBP21zQnLe+0MgoLC6vBJldVAKLLl7eVYkztWaEDdboCvp6+T6ajApcdbCwucWU6sf94U9P4v4+0klGZ0+yCc/hLwn1Sxlfg9dlByuVy', '2ToERP8VaSfkfrpGTn37I75lZ9Q9ZRHIIU56w5GAZ8MWp');
```

But when I try to implement it into my code. It doesn't decrypt.

```
function decrypttest($message)
{
    $servername = ""; //host
    $username = ""; //username
    $password = ""; //password
    
    try {
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=ADataBase", $username, $password);
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo 'Error';
      die();
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `programs` WHERE `authtoken` = '$program'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 4);
    $encrypted = $message;
    $password = $row[0]; //This is the $enckey from example 1.
    $method = 'aes-256-cbc';
    $password = substr(hash('sha256', $password, true), 0, 32);
    $iv = chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0);
    $decrypted = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($encrypted), $method, $password, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    
    return $decrypted;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, but what I'm trying to say is, it decrypts when the aes key is there, but when I try to decrypt after grabbing the aes key from mysql (Which it does successfully, I checked). It doesn't decrypt and I have no idea why.

Comment: Have you compared `bin2hex($password)` for both codes, where `$password` is the value  that is passed _directly_ to `openssl_encrypt`?

Comment: No, but I will now, thanks so much!